# How to pass jQuery multiselect values from View to Controller

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have added a multi select jQuery widget to my MVC Application. I am able to populate data in that multiselect listbox with checkboxes and able to select data. I am not able to post the selected data to Controller. Searched a lot in internet, but am not able to make it.

Here is my code.

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#printers").multiselect(
            {
                click: function (event, ui)
                {
                    jQuery.post('@Url.Action("Device/Create")', { value: ui.value }, function (data) { }, 'json'); 
                }
            });
    });  
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>DataBE</legend>
     <h2>Create Data</h2>
         <div id="lists" style="float: left; width: 200px; line-height: 40px; margin-right: 30px"> 
                <select multiple="multiple" id="printers" name="printers" size="10">
                    @foreach (var names in @Model.SeletedPrinters)
                    {
                        var optionID = "option" + names.Value;                                                  
                        <option value="@optionID">@names.Text</option>
                    }
                </select>
                </div>   
        }
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(DataWrapper wrapper, List<string> selectedValues, FormCollection collection)
{
}
```

please help me on how to pass the selected data from list box to controller.

Comment: Append selected values in URL (queryStirng) on close event of multiselect and then extract parameter from request.

Comment: are you loading the jquery library before your script? Do you get any error in browser's console?

Comment: Hi Parkash, Can you post the code? I am not able to get what you are asking me to do as i am new to both MVC and Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to me that you are not referencing to the jquery library before the script you have posted here.

Try adding this library before your script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```